# Lucene.NET numbered paragraphs not found

Tags: lucene.net

I'm building a search engine and everything seems okay except searching for numbered paragraphs.
For example, in one of the indexed documents, there is a list like this:
1. Sagittal T1 inversion.
2. ....
3. ....
If I search for the exact phrase "T1 inversion" the document is found. If, however, I search for the exact phrase "Sagittal T1 inversion", that document is not found. Any documents where that phrase is not the start of a numbered paragraph, are found.

The query looks like this:
+ReportText:"Sagittal T1 Inversion"

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated... Thank you.

Mihai

Comment: I recommend you'll try this basic tutorial: http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/29/LuceneNet-Tutorial.aspx

Comment: What analyzer and tokenizer are you using for that field?